Using keys of an object to iterate over some properties of another object in TypeScript
Here is the code and the code online
interface DataInterface {
  a: string[];
  b: string[];
  c: number[];
  d: number[];
  e: boolean[];
  x: string
  y: number
}

const dataObject: DataInterface = {
        "a": [
          "{$prefix} {$x}"
        ],
        "b": [
          "temp {$x}"
        ],
        "c": [
          3.8
        ],
        "d": [
          0,
          50
        ],
        "e": [
          true,
          false
        ],
        "x": "world",
        "y": 1,
      }
      
const tableArrays: {[index: string]:any} = {
  a: ["{$prefix} {$x}"],
  b: ["world {$x}"],
  c: [0, 50],
  d: [3.8],
  e: [true,false],
}
for (const tableArray in tableArrays) {
  dataObject[tableArray] = Array.from({
    ...tableArrays[tableArray],
    length: 5,
  })
  dataObject[tableArray].fill(
    tableArrays[tableArray][tableArrays[tableArray].length - 1],
    tableArrays[tableArray].length
  )
  for (let i = 0; i < dataObject[tableArray].length; i++) {
    if (typeof dataObject[tableArray][i] === 'string') {
      dataObject[tableArray][i] = dataObject[tableArray][i].replace('{$x}', i)
      dataObject[tableArray][i] = dataObject[tableArray][i].replace('{$prefix}', "hello")
    }
  }
  if (tableArray === 'b') {
    dataObject[tableArray].pop()
  }
}

console.log(dataObject)

This errors with Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'DataInterface'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'DataInterface'.
I've tried asserting that the tableArray variable will only be a key in DataInterface with
type BuildingTableKeys = keyof BuildingTable;

// Iterate over the keys of tableArrays
for (const tableArray of Object.keys(tableArrays) as BuildingTableKeys[]) {...}

but that results in Conversion of type '{ [index: string]: any[]; }' to type '(keyof DataInterface)[]' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first. All of my attempts to convert to unknown resulted in more errors.
I've tried asserting that index is is DataInterface using in and keyof to no avail.
const tableArrays: {[index: keyof DataInterface]:any}

gives An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.
const tableArrays: {[index in DataInterface]:any}

gives Type 'DataInterface' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
I've attempted most of the answers here and here but couldn't get any to work.

There are a bunch of errors in there, at least some of which you're not asking about (e.g., parseInt(4)? why not just 4?) Please [edit] this code to be a [mre] where the only problems present are the ones you're asking about, and preferably pare it down to just a few lines where the errors happen. Maybe you can dispense with x and y for now and then deal with adding them back later? Maybe don't worry about the replace() bit if you care mostly about getting indexing to work to start with? This might turn out to be multiple questions in one.

@jcalz sorry done, I hadn't realised editing the code online would affect the code in the link. I've removed the parse(4) (remnant of my real code where the 4 is a variable.) Now there are 8 identical errors No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'DataInterface'

The basic approach when iterating over x but indexing into y is to either assert that you know that the keys you get are in y as shown here, or to check at runtime that the keys are in y as shown here. Neither addresses the subsequent problems you'll face, but those are out of scope here (or else the question really is about multiple things).  Hitting more errors isn't indicative that your initial approach was wrong, it often means you've overcome one problem and have to face the next one. How would you like to proceed here?

I extended the interface and included an index signature.
interface DataInterface {
  a: string[];
  b: string[];
  c: number[];
  d: number[];
  e: boolean[];
  x: string;
  y: number;
}

interface DataInterfaceIndex extends DataInterface {
  [index: string]: any;
}

const dataObject: DataInterfaceIndex = {
  a: ["{$prefix} {$x}"],
  b: ["temp {$x}"],
  c: [3.8],
  d: [0, 50],
  e: [true, false],
  x: "world",
  y: 1,
};

const tableArrays: Partial<DataInterfaceIndex> = {
  a: ["{$prefix} {$x}"],
  b: ["world {$x}"],
  c: [0, 50],
  d: [3.8],
  e: [true, false],
};

for (const key in tableArrays) {
  console.log(tableArrays[key])
  console.log(dataObject[key])
}

console.log(dataObject);

I'm pretty sure this is a bad way to do this as it allows any properties to be added. So I extended the interface rather than modify the original, but I think this still isn't ideal.
